# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net

I have been programming a game using C#, Visual Studio and the Monogame Framework. Today i reopened the program after a long time on a new computer and also upgraded the monogame framework.

However, when i try to compile, i get this error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Kan bestand of assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a of een van de afhankelijkheden hiervan niet laden. Het systeem kan het opgegeven bestand niet vinden.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I am absolutely new to anything *.dll-related, so i have no clue where to start searching.

Thanx a lot!

Comment: if you're using the files(System.IO) related code, be ensure the mentioned file is exist or not in the path.

Comment: Dear Balaji, thank you for your swift reply. Which file specifically should i check to see if it exists? I have specifically added all references to my project and also tried to add all references related to System.IO, however that didn't work as well. Hope you can give me a further hint!

Comment: That based on your code, for example if you read files from d:/temp/new.txt the file should be available otherwise the error will be throw. You need to debug and ensure the file is available or not

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for a while.

It turned out to be because I had the [assembly: AssemblyCulture("en")] attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs set to "en". Once I removed the "en" and put it back to [assembly: AssemblyCulture("")] this error was resolved. I think the error was being thrown because I did not have any culture folders in my build output directory.

The answer on this [page](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1101282/An-unhandled-exception-of-type-system-io-filenotfo) helped me figure out what my problem was.